# How can I define select one element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$(".add_more_file").on("click", function(){
  var $input = $(this).siblings('input').clone();
  $input.insertBefore($(this));
})
```

```css
a, input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w_activity_licenses_inputs">
    <input  class="upload"  type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />
    <a class="add_more_file" style="display:block">Add more file</a>
</div>
```

When I click on that button twice, I will have 4 inputs. While I want to have 2 inputs. I know, it's because for the second time, two elements will be matched in the siblings function. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is using `.prev()` *(which only selects the previous element, not all previous ones)* instead of `.siblings()`. Try this:

```js
$(".add_more_file").on("click", function() {
  var $input = $(this).prev('input').clone().val("");
  $input.insertBefore($(this));
})
```

```css
a,
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w_activity_licenses_inputs">
  <input class="upload" type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />
  <a class="add_more_file" style="display:block">Add more file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. upvote, just one thing, when you select a image, and then add one more input, that input is also containing that selected element. How can I make a new raw input?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.first()` function to get just first sibling element.

```js
    $(".add_more_file").on("click", function(){
      var $input = $(this).siblings('input').first().clone();
          $input.insertBefore($(this));
    })
```

```css
a, input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w_activity_licenses_inputs">
    <input  class="upload"  type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />
    <a class="add_more_file" style="display:block">Add more file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. upvote, just one thing, when you select a image, and then add one more input, that input is also containing that selected element. How can I make a new raw input?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `siblings('input')` selects all the input elements in the div, which is 1 in the first click, 2 in the second one etc.

Select only 1 input for clone, you can keep a reference to the original element and keep cloning it

```js
var $file = $('.w_activity_licenses_inputs input.upload');
$(".add_more_file").on("click", function() {
  $file.clone().insertBefore(this);
})
```

```css
a,
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w_activity_licenses_inputs">
  <input class="upload" type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />
  <a class="add_more_file" style="display:block">Add more file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. upvote, just one thing, when you select a image, and then add one more input, that input is also containing that selected element. How can I make a new raw input?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(this).siblings('input:eq(0)')` to target the first input. To clear the in input value if exists use `.val("")`:

```js
$(".add_more_file").on("click", function(){
  var $input = $(this).siblings("input:eq(0)").clone().val("");
  // val("") will clear the value from cloned input if there is any
  $input.insertBefore($(this));
});
```

```css
a, input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w_activity_licenses_inputs">
    <input  class="upload"  type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />
    <a class="add_more_file" style="display:block">Add more file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. upvote, just one thing, when you select a image, and then add one more input, that input is also containing that selected element. How can I make a new raw input?

Comment: @MartinAJ, You can clear the value of the input if there is any with `$($input).val("")`  just before inserting. Please check the updated answer.... thanks for upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'input:first'` to only select first input and not all or use `$('<input  class="upload"  type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />')` to create a brand new input element

```js
    $(".add_more_file").on("click", function(){
      var $input = $('<input  class="upload"  type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />');
          $input.insertBefore($(this));
    })
```

```css
a, input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w_activity_licenses_inputs">
    <input  class="upload"  type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />
    <a class="add_more_file" style="display:block">Add more file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. upvote, just one thing, when you select a image, and then add one more input, that input is also containing that selected element. How can I make a new raw input?

Answer (score 1):

Use `last()` to clone only the  last input.

```js
$(".add_more_file").on("click", function(){
      var $input = $(this).siblings('input').last().clone().val("");
          $input.insertBefore($(this));
    })
```

```css
a, input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
a{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w_activity_licenses_inputs">
    <input  class="upload"  type="file" name="activity_licenses" required />
    <a class="add_more_file" style="display:block">Add more file</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. upvote, just one thing, when you select a image, and then add one more input, that input is also containing that selected element. How can I make a new raw input?

Comment: @MartinAJ Check the updated answer. `.val("")` will clone the input without the selected file.